# Why I get these strange characters with scrapy instead of html?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

It's just a hobby task for me. I try to get booking.com start page html via scappy.

```
  def start_requests(self):
        print('step 1')
        start_url = 'https://www.booking.com'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=start_url, headers=self.headers, callback=self.step2)

    def step2(self, response):
        print('step 2')
        print(response.status)
        print(response.headers)
        print(response.text)
```

and I get something strange in response.text. This is the part of response :

> O�����xa�X��_\O^'IM�l�F��6(]1�r��LB>�O�g�#p.�:x�}8Rh���ӓ�Q���2h��ƺU�s�&���0{���l]*Y&�����F9�@�WCR��������7�**)JE-�-��&��
>   )ԼS����y���z�R�@�J�����1���N��60��&'�lK�E�`R.Ҙɧ�e���S��ϵ��C�(��6$�&���L2���������{���B^�@��~~['�              ����T2�|"|��X�L
>   5˔-�خ� A`J�8��X�@5`�y*���:���O���⎻��␊��R��71┴�A"≠�Eٹ����[�9B��6,����#�$0%(L�2'°��≤≥�&�Ď�Lȋ7�                                   <����*p�ABU�ālK�=���iݐ�'�b>I�'�J��o7�����e�|
>                                                                                               �≥�4�*�Vď�L�0����◆�xՒPef����&l��d{X�h���#�� q$�d�$����?�:�M��&jb{���0������@�
>                                                                                                                                                                            ���S�_�����4ztlS��4�2^�����5^�7'� QFUH:��7▒��│        �┘�.�����ݔ��M�␋�ȵ����A⎽┼:�Z�:��F��├�D�-߯8*������ǠH*��ؔ│�J�C�oe2|��}xo�&��"K��j�y�<�%Z�;!M��t ۩~�R�cy2�>D�h�p���3�4���x�y1��T\���IY��F�(�E��ì� �[

This looks like fake data. Every time a response is different. When i try to do a similar request via a posman all working good. I get code - 302 response with a link that opens the site without errors.
I think booking detects that my code is a scraper, but I don't understand how. IP address the same with the postman, postman also ignored javascript, so I don't know what happens. Help me, please. Thank you!

Comment: Don't know scrapy but maybe what you get is a compressed response from the server and scrapy doesn't decompress it before returning it to your script.

Comment: That website appears to have an [api](https://developers.booking.com/api/index.html).. why not use that instead of trying to scrape data?

Comment: @luis.parravicini yes, this was a reason for my troubles. See solution from xlrtx

Comment: @Sayse They do not provide API for all persons who want. I was trying to get API key, but with no success. This looks strange because anyways I'll pay for hotels via booking.com.  But these are their rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting raw compressed response, which is quite strange, normally `scrapy` would handle HTTP session and compressed data all by itself thanks to `CookiesMiddleware` and `HttpCompressionMiddleware`, they are both enabled by default. Did you hard-coded `Accept-Encoding` in your code?

```sh
# Content-Encoding set to gzip in response, since client supports it.
curl -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -v https://www.booking.com 1>/dev/null 2>&1 | grep content-encoding

# It shows binary data, you can decompress with -c
curl -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' https://www.booking.com
curl -c -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' https://www.booking.com

# No Content-Encoding from response if the client don't want gzip.
curl -v https://www.booking.com 1>/dev/null 2>&1 | grep content-encoding
```

Comment: Oh, men! In my headers I've set :

_'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',_ !
 Hence, I get compressed data! Once I removed this from header all working good! Thank you!

Comment: Cheers, `Accept-Encoding` header is set by default if you didn't disable `httpcompression` middleware. https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1fd1702a11a56ecbe9851ba4f9d3c10797e262dd/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/httpcompression.py

Answer (score 1):

I'm late here but I would like to post an answer that could be helpful.

The page you requested seems to be compressed based on brotli. Currently, Scrapy won't handle decompressing it unless you have brotlipy installed in your dependencies then scrapy will be making use of it to decompress this.

```
pip install brotlipy
```

Just install brotlipy and give it a spin.

There is an open issue [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/4698) in Scrapy addressing the same to include brotlipy as a hard dependency.

I would highly recommend not to remove '**Accept-Encoding**' as it will be helpful in maintaining lower bandwidth consumption that too if you are using proxies that is billed based on usage this will help in reducing the cost.